# ORACLE PL SQL Extracting a value from SOAP XML

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I have an oracle procedure that uses UTL_HTTP to make a request to a SOAP service

Here is the response being returned as evidenced by dbms_output.put_line(responseText);

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<CreateProductionTicketResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<CreateProductionTicketResult>246300</CreateProductionTicketResult>
<err />
</CreateProductionTicketResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I then create an XMLTYPE object

```
responseXml := XMLTYPE(responseText);
```

and attempt to pull the value of CreateProductionTicketResult

```
TICKET_ID := responseXML.EXTRACT('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/CreateProductionTicketResponse/CreateProductionTicketResult/text()', 'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"').getnumberval();
```

This line throws the error

```
ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed
ORA-06512: at line 41
30625. 00000 -  "method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed"
*Cause:    A member method of a type is being invoked with a NULL SELF
           argument.
*Action:   Change the method invocation to pass in a valid self argument.
```

I'm guessing I screwed up the EXTRACT syntax, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the second, unnamed namespace in the response node (and implicitly inherited by the result node). You can give that a dummy name in the second argument to extract, and use that in the XPath (the names don't have to match the original doc as long as the URL matches):

```
TICKET_ID := responseXML.EXTRACT('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/anon:CreateProductionTicketResponse/anon:CreateProductionTicketResult/text()',
               'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:anon="http://tempuri.org/"').getnumberval();
```